# Controlling the influence of the number of matched clauses on the score in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

By default, Solr multiplies the score of each document by the coordination factor - the portion of matched query clauses - so that the more clauses that match the higher the score. I would like to be able to control the extent to which the coordination factor affects the score. In other words, I would like to add a query-time-configurable boost to the coordination factor. Currently, the only only query-time-configurable parameter is to either enable or disable the coordination factor. That parameter doesn't allow me to increase or decrease the coordination factor significance. How can I add such a parameter to Solr?

Any solution that lets me affect the score according to the portion of matched clauses that's configurable in query time will be accepted, even if it doesn't have anything to do with the coordination factor.

Answer (score 0):

I see, the easy and powerfull way to do that is to use the "query boost". You can use query time boost in order to boost some results

```
Example 1 : q=country:brazil^10 sport:soccer
objective of this query:  select city that has sport "soccer" and we will have a preference for the country of brazil!
```

[Take a look to the reference documentation.](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Field_Based_Boosting)

is that what you wanted to have? give me some feedback please!